# How to insert or import json format data into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to import json nested data into mongodb but not working.I do not know why it is not importing.I am not getting any error but not importing.May be some mistake in my json format data? Anybody know please help me to find solution.
Below given my code.

data.model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchemaOrder = new mongoose.Schema({

    voice: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    mobile: {
        type: Number
    },
    ordered: [{
        link: String,
        itemid: String,
        item: String,
        unitcost: Number,
        qty: Number,
        total: Number
    }],
    state: {
        type: String
    },
    address: [{
        link: String,
        address1: String,
        address2: String,
        city: String,
        zipcode: Number
    }],
    todayDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    afterfiveDays: {
        type: Date
    }


}, {
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'order',
    toObject: { getters: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', userSchemaOrder);
```

Trying to import this data.

data.text:

```
{
  "voice": "V-258",
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
  "mobile": 000000000,
  "ordered": [ {
    "link":"Ordered",
    "itemid": "Cs1",
    "item": "Choco",
    "unitcost": 1,
    "qty": 2,
    "total": 850
  }],
  "state":"Kerala",
  "address":[{
    "link": "Address",
    "address1": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "address2": "yyyyyyyyyy",
    "city": "zzzzzzzzzz",
    "zipcode": 000000
  }],
  "todayDate": "2020-06-06",
  "afterfiveDays": "2020-06-06" 
}
```

Comment: can u show me the code where you tried to create the Document ?

Comment: @AliJixer: Import Data button is there in mongodb application